# Lisp relics in LaTeXe logo

Tags: macros

I always thought TeX's macros are very Lispy like and stumbling across the definition of the LaTeXe logo confirmed it. The macro is defined as follows:

```
%\LaTeXe The LATEX2" logo as proposed by A-W designers.
 \def\LaTeXe{%
   \mbox{\m@th%
    \if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\boldmath\fi
     \LaTeX\kern.15em2$_{\textstyle\varepsilon}$}}
```

So what does the `\@car` do?

Introduced in the Lisp programming language, `car` and `cdr` are primitive operations upon linked lists composed of `cons cells`.

When `cons` cells are used to implement singly-linked lists (rather than trees and other more complicated structures), the `car` operation returns the first element of the list, while `cdr` returns the rest of the list.

How does the `@car` work and what is `@nil`? As far as I can see, it is undefined, but does not give an error. It does not even give an error even if I define it as `\def\@nil{illdefined!}`, as shown in the code below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}

\bigskip
\makeatletter
\def\@nil{illdefined!}
\scalebox{5}{\LaTeXe}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

More on CAR and CDR at the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The link to Lisp is quite true (it's mentioned somewhere in the sources, but I can't put my finger on it just now). The way this works is very simple. The definitions are

```
\def\@car#1#2\@nil{#1}
\def\@cdr#1#2\@nil{#2}
```

In this context, `\@nil` is being used as a delimiter, so what it expands to does not matter at all. This is a classic 'delimited argument' situation in TeX. (The only thing that is important is that TeX finds the appropriate token in the input stream, in this case before any `\par` tokens.) TeX will allow us one blank the last item of this type of delimited macro to be empty. As a result, both `\@cdr` and `\@car` need to have at least one token supplied: something like

```
\expandafter\@cdr\@empty\@nil
```

will give an error.

Notice that these are TeX functions, not Lisp ones, and so we get the first <*balanced text*> separated off from the rest.

Comment: In plain LaTeX, `\@nil` is undefined, isn't it? How do you get `\@@nil`?

Comment: Must be mistaken: I'm sure I've seen that somewhere, but I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Hendrik, I was thinking of `\@nnil`, which is used by the looping system in LaTeX2e and is defined `\def\@nnil{\@nil}`.

Comment: `\meaning\@nil` gives `undefined`, but does not seem to affect the scanning, since I defined it as `\def\@nil{Illdefined!}` and still prints the logo with no complaints. Will read Chapter 20 once more, and yes of course is not Lisp, but Lispy!

Comment: on your last line: shouldn't it be the last `<balanced text>` rather than token?

Answer (score 18):

To expand a bit on Joseph's answer: The `\@nil` is just a macro delimiter that is only seen when the arguments of `\@car` are scanned, and it is never expanded. For example `\@car` can be invoked by `\@car123\@nil`, and the result is `1`, whereas `\@cdr123\@nil` yields `23`. You *cannot* use `\@car123`; then TeX will continue to scan tokens since it want's to find the matching `\@nil` that is a required part in the invocation of `\@car`. As Joseph already pointed out, using `\@car\@nil` also gives an error.

For more info about this I recommend reading Chapter 20 in the TeXbook, in particular page 202.

Comment: I was just adding a shorter bit of text about the same thing!

Comment: @Joseph: And your answer appeared when I was typing mine, so I could make it a bit shorter before posting ...

Comment: @Hendrik From what you describe, I guess any delimiter could have been used for example `\def\@car#1#2]{#1}` and then the list should have been `\@car\f@series]'.

Comment: @Yiannis Indeed, all that is important when TeX does scanning for delimited arguments is finding the appropriate token(s). So you can use _whatever you like_ as the end marker, provided you (1) know it won't be in the real input, and (2) remember to include it as the end marker!

Comment: @Yiannis: And it's not just about end markers, but also about separators, so guess how you would invoke a macro defined by `\def\stupid#1: #2(\whatever)#3{#3,#2,#1}`. (Yes, also spaces can be used here.)

Comment: Also remember that the category code of the delimiters is important: you see this in things like LaTeX2e's `\strip@pt` system, where there is some work to do so that the delimiting 'pt' are not letters but 'other' characters.

Comment: In `\@car c\@nil`, what is the #2 of `\@car`, \empty, \@nil, \relax? If #2 is `\@nil`, then what is the argument delimiter?