# list processing for file to input

Tags: lists, input, files

i would like to create a 'list' of file names at arbitrary points in a document and use that list in the appendix to load these files. i understand that there's a generalized concept of a list in TeX for holding items to be lay-outed but i'm looking for a simple way of flexibly adding to a a list of items and at a later point iterate over these items to interpret these as '\input{item}'.

i googled around a bit but nothing came up that seems to match. so, if that has been already answered i'm happy to just follow a link.

EDIT: looking at the answers i just realized that it might be useful to keep the list items unique, i.e. adding the same file name twice would not load the file twice. would that be possible (at a reasonable level of simplicity)?

Comment: For your `unique` request see my updated example at the bottom of my answer, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standard list management in the LaTeX kernel, based on `\@for`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addtofilelist}[1]{%
  \ifx\files@to@input@later\@empty
    \g@addto@macro\files@to@input@later{#1}%
  \else
    \g@addto@macro\files@to@input@later{,#1}%
  \fi
}
\let\files@to@input@later\@empty % initialize

\newcommand{\inputthefiles}{%
   \@for\next:=\files@to@input@later\do{\input{\next}}%
}
\makeatother
```

So you say

```
\addtofilelist{foo.tex}

\addtofilelist{bar.tex}
```

when you want and at the end you can issue

```
\inputthefiles
```

that will act as required.

---

An `expl3` based technique:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtofilelist}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_regnirpsj_file_list_seq { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\inputthefiles}{}
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_regnirpsj_file_list_seq { \input{ ##1 } }
 }
\seq_new:N \g_regnirpsj_file_list_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The usage is the same. If you want to be able to add a list of files with a single `\addtofilelist` command, change the first definition into

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtofilelist}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_regnirpsj_file_list_seq { ##1 }
   }
 }
```

and you'll be able to say, at any given point

```
\addtofilelist{foo.tex, bar.tex}
```

with any number of file names separated by commas. This is also possible with the kernel based solution, but beware that spaces are not allowed in that case, whereas they're ignored around commas in the `xparse` based solution.

Comment: the latex kernel `\@for` solution seems really nice, because i could look at the `\next` item. however, it produces an error:
`Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \next 
<argument> \next 
                 \empty`

Comment: @regnirpsj I get no error with `article`; with `beamer` it's quite difficult to say something, because there are too many variables: are you doing `\addtofilelist` in a frame? Beware that the code in a frame may be executed multiple times.

Comment: no the filelist adding is outside a frame-env. i can `\typeout{\next}` but `\input{\next}` for the list-end(?) seems to fail. could it be that beamer (re-)defines `\@empty`/`\empty` somewhere?

Comment: using (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100633/) brought me to the idea of using `\input\next` instead of `\input{\next}`; that works.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done e.g. with `etoolbox` list - utilities.

Use, for example, `\listgadd{\myfilelist}{}` as initializer for a list.

Afterwards, at 'any' position use `\listgadd{\myfilelist}{file1}` or for a bunch of files `\forcsvlist{\listgadd{\myfilelist}}{file2, file3,file4}`.

To input all files in the appendix, it's good to have a wrapper command, that does some work before and after input of each file, but it would suffice to say

`\forlistloop{\input}{\myfilelist}`,

which iterates through the list.

The first argument to all list iterator macros from `etoolbox` expect an element routine, which gets the current list element as last argument.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%

\listgadd{\myfilelist}{}%


\newcommand{\inputallfiles}[1]{%
\input{#1}%
}%

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\listgadd{\myfilelist}{file1}%

\blindtext[10]

\forcsvlist{\listgadd{\myfilelist}}{file2,file3,file1}%


\appendix%

\section{First}

\forlistloop{\inputallfiles}{\myfilelist}%

\end{document}
```

## file1.tex

```
\textit{Hello World}
```

## file2.tex

```
\textbf{Hello World}
```

## file3.tex

```
\textsc{Hello World}
```

[image]

## As the OP requested a unique adding of list elements -- alternative version

Using a wrapper command for the addition of list elements, it is possible to check, if a 'new' element is already stored in the list, using the `ifinlist` command from etoolbox. If this test results `false`, it can be added, otherwise, it is ignored.

I added a `command` `\addtofilelist` which works for single elements or comma-separated list of elements as well.

In the `\inputallfiles` macro I added the test `\InputIfFileExists...` for more safety.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%

\listgadd{\myfilelist}{}%


\newcommand{\uniqueaddtolist}[2]{%
  \ifdef{#1}{%
    \ifinlist{#2}{#1}{%
      % Do nothing 
    }{%
      \listgadd{#1}{#2}%
    }
  }{% No list so far, so just add one!
    \listgadd{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}%

\newcommand{\uniqueaddtofilelist}[1]{%
  \uniqueaddtolist{\myfilelist}{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\addtofilelist}[1]{%
  \forcsvlist{\uniqueaddtofilelist}{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\inputallfiles}[1]{%
\InputIfFileExists{#1}{}{}%
}%

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\addtofilelist{file1}%

\blindtext[10]

\addtofilelist{file2,file3,file1}%


\appendix%

\section{First}

\forlistloop{\inputallfiles}{\myfilelist}%

\end{document}
```