# Deleting an element from a comma separated list

Tags: tex-core, comma-separated-list

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5754/comma-delimited-lists#5756) we learnt how to remove the *n*-th element from a comma-separated list.

How can I remove an element from a list by its *value*, rather than its *position*? For example: if my global variable `\citylist` currently has the value `derby,leicester,nottingham`, then after executing `\removecity{leicester}` I would like it to have the value `derby,nottingham`.

I already have an `\addcity` macro (which I made by adapting [a macro by David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97901/how-can-i-store-variables-in-lists-and-make-use-of-them#97927)):

```
\newcommand\addcity[1]{%
  \ifx\citylist\@empty\else\g@addto@macro\citylist{,}\fi
  \g@addto@macro\citylist{#1}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In simple cases, you can use LaTeX's `\@removeelement`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\citylist}{derby,leicester,nottingham}

\makeatletter
\@expandtwoargs\@removeelement{leicester}\citylist\citylist
\makeatother

\typeout{\citylist}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Result:

> `derby,nottingham`

Simple means, the list is normalized without optional spaces around the comma.
The list elements does not contain commas and macros.

A variant with package `kvsetkeys`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kvsetkeys}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addcity}[1]{%
  \ifx\citylist\@empty\else\g@addto@macro\citylist{,}\fi
  \g@addto@macro\citylist{#1}
}

\newcommand*{\removecity}[1]{%
  \def\unwanted@city{#1}%
  \edef\citylist{\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\comma@parse\expandafter{\citylist}\@removecity
}
\newcommand*{\@removecity}[1]{%
  \def\param@city{#1}%
  \ifx\param@city\unwanted@city
  \else
    \addcity{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\citylist}{derby,leicester,nottingham}
\removecity{leicester}
\typeout{\citylist}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Then spaces do not disturb, e.g.:

```
\newcommand*{\citylist}{derby, leicester, nottingham}
```

The city names may contain commands and fragile macros, they are not
expanded.

With the following definition for `\addcity`, the city names might even contain commas:

```
\newcommand*{\addcity}[1]{%
  \ifx\citylist\@empty\else\g@addto@macro\citylist{,}\fi
  \g@addto@macro\citylist{{#1}}
}
```

Example for a list:

> `{derby},{leicester},{berlin, west},{berlin, east}`

Answer (score 7):

The [`expl3`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) suite can manage comma separated lists in many ways.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\createlist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_new:c { g_wickerson_data_#1_clist }
  \clist_gset:cn { g_wickerson_data_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_gput_right:cn { g_wickerson_data_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\removefromlist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_gremove_all:cn { g_wickerson_data_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\purgelist}{m}
 {
  \clist_gremove_duplicates:c { g_wickerson_data_#1_clist }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printlist}{m}
 {
  \clist_use:cnnn { g_wickerson_data_#1_clist } { ,~ } { ,~ } { ,~ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_use:Nnnn { c }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%%% working with a specific list without needing two args
\newcommand{\addcity}[1]{\addtolist{city}{#1}}
\newcommand{\removecity}[1]{\removefromlist{city}{#1}}
\newcommand{\printcity}{\printlist{city}}

\createlist{city}{derby,leicester} % initialization

\begin{document}

\addcity{nottingham}

Cities: \printcity

\bigskip

\removecity{leicester}

Cities: \printcity

\end{document}
```

However, comma lists are not the most efficient data type: sequences are better. And the internal implementation shouldn't be a concern.

The same is achieved in a faster way with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\createlist}{mm}
 {
  \seq_new:c { g_wickerson_data_#1_seq }
  \seq_gset_from_clist:cn { g_wickerson_data_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolist}{mm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g_wickerson_data_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\removefromlist}{mm}
 {
  \seq_gremove_all:cn { g_wickerson_data_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\purgelist}{m}
 {
  \seq_gremove_duplicates:c { g_wickerson_data_#1_seq }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printlist}{m}
 {
  \seq_use:cnnn { g_wickerson_data_#1_seq } { ,~ } { ,~ } { ,~ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nnnn { c }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%%% working with a specific list without needing two args
\newcommand{\addcity}[1]{\addtolist{city}{#1}}
\newcommand{\removecity}[1]{\removefromlist{city}{#1}}
\newcommand{\printcity}{\printlist{city}}

\createlist{city}{derby,leicester} % initialize

\begin{document}

\addcity{nottingham}

Cities: \printcity

\bigskip

\removecity{leicester}

Cities: \printcity

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @egreg. Unfortunately, when I run your first program, I get the error "Command '\clist_use:Nnnn' not yet defined!", and from your second program I get "Command '\seq_use:Nnnn' not yet defined!". I'm running pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011) -- do I need to update?

Comment: @JohnWickerson You definitely need to update. TeX Live 2011 is very outdated with respect to `expl3`. Note that TL 2013 is in testing phase, but it's surely worthy to upgrade to TL 2012.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. I'm now on pdfTeX Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012), but I still get an error, albeit now with a slightly more fashionable wording: "Control sequence \clist_use:Nnnn undefined."

Comment: sounds more than strange. can you post the log file somewhere?

Comment: @JohnWickerson You have to run `tlmgr` and update fully.

Comment: D'oh, of course. Thanks @egreg, that's all working happily now.