# When do I need invoke \clearpage manually?

Tags: floats, page-breaking, header-footer

I am not sure whether  invoking `\clearpage` is necessary or redundant at many places in my input `.tex` files.

Here I will ask you, in what condition is invoking `\clearpage` necessary?

I hope I get a list of all possible condition that might be also useful for others.

In my daily work, I do as follows:

1. If I need a new page for the next stuff, I put `\clearpage` right before the stuff.
2. If I need to change the header/footer style for the next stuff, I put `\clearpage` followed by `\pagestyle` right before the stuff.
3. If I get a "too many floots" error, I put `\clearpage` at the end of every 5 consecutive floats.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the question. You should use `\clearpage` and `\newpage` whenever you want a new page. When do *you* think you're using it inappropriately?

Comment: @Will: thanks for commenting. Please see my update. @Yiannis: It is worth seeing my update too.

Comment: for item 3) if you get this error often it is advisable to use the "morefloats" package, for an explanation see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8212/an-explanation-of-latexs-output-routine/8736#8736 . Classes such as the `tufte-book` incorporate this package in the class definitions.

Comment: again for 3: you might be underspecifying where your floats can appear. You should *always* write your document with either `[tbp]` or `[htbp]` to give the floats some room and only start constraining them when the document is finished. Or you might just be using too many floats `:)`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In general, you do not need any `\clearpage` because page breaking should be done automatically by the TeX engine. However, in some cases, eg having lots of images or equations, one has to insert a manually pagebreak.

- `\newpage` ends the page immediately at the current position and starts a new page without any stretching of the page
- `\pagebreak[value]` ends the page *after* the current line and stretches the vertical page to end up on the lower page border, if there is any material with glue
- `\clearpage` outputs all active floats and ends the page like `\newpage`
- `\cleardoublepage` same for double sided documents

With the package `nextpage` one can also use the macros `\cleartoevenpage` and `\cleartooddpage`

Answer (score 14):

I think others have given good answers, but if you find yourself needing to use `\clearpage` to flush out floats, then it's usually better to use the `afterpage` package to clear the floats at the end of the page.

```
\afterpage{\clearpage}
```

That way you don't just end the page right there; you end the page at the normal break point.

Comment: It gives error - undefined control sequence

Comment: @lokeshkumar You didn't say which was undefined. Does your preamble contain `\usepackage{afterpage}`?

Comment: Yeah it contains that line. Still giving error - undefined control sequence pointing at \afterpage{\clearpage}

Comment: @lokeshkumar you should ask a new question and point to this one. It should work (and does for me). I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 13):

The use of `\clearpage` in an author's document should be limited to only a few instances. The command should be used in class files normally in places such as the definitions for chapter, title,appendix, bibliography, toc  and the like.

With a well written class the author should never really need to insert a `\clearpage` command. However, there maybe instances (especially when someone has too many floats) that one needs to enforce a pagebreak and the printing of floats. In this case the `\clearpage` command is recommended.

Comment: @Yiannis: Your answer is NOT clear when I (as an document author) should use `\clearpage` in the input file.

Comment: @xport Never really! But I will modify the answer:)

Comment: @Yiannis: how about when changing the pagestyle?

Comment: @xport Do you want the author to do this? Shouldn't the author for example just type `\mainmatter`?

Comment: @Yiannis: when I change some pages containing long table from potrait to landscape, I must change the page style.

Comment: @xport If you do this often enough, then it is best to define a 'landscapepage` or `landscapetable` command and place it in the class file or a package. In general the author should be typing contents and not worry about the looks of the page; that belongs to the class author.

Comment: @xport Just thinking aloud I would give this type of table a more semantic name such as `readonceeverytenyearstable` as landscape tables are really unreadable and very few people would bother reading them :)