# Tables float into bibliography

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a sequence of sections of my paper, followed by a bibliography (bibtex).

It looks pretty much like

```
\input{asection}
\input{appendix}
\bibliography(bibfile}
```

The problem is, "appendix" contains several tables, and they're being intersperesed among the bibliography. I want to have all of the tables, then the bibliography.

Adding a page break between sections or writing `\begin{table}[h!]` is not working. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: See also [How to avoid splitting tables between sections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/how-to-avoid-splitting-tables-between-sections).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want the `\clearpage` command. It forces LaTeX to push out all floating objects (figures and tables), and start a new page. Just put it in the source before you begin the appendix.

A Google search for `\clearpage` should point you to plenty more references if you want them.

Comment: You might want to combine it with `\afterpage` from the `afterpage` package. See [When do I need invoke \clearpage manually?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9191/when-do-i-need-invoke-clearpage-manually) for more details.