# Figure goes to the end of the section

Tags: floats, positioning

I am writing a paper using TeX, and I want to make this;

> bla bla.... page of text but talking about Fig.1 bla bla

---

> New page with only the Fig. No text

---

> New page with text bla bla

I tried 
`\begin{figure}[p]`
but it put the figure to the end of the chapter.
I tried here,
but whatever I do, I get either
   the picture inside the paragraph with other text 
   or the picture at the end of the chapter.

Comment: then it is bigger than `\textwidth` and/or `\textheight`. Test it by setting `\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm]{...}`

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, it normally helps to provide a comple small document that shows the problem but here see  related questions such as the one linked automatically in the related list http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11366/how-can-i-get-the-figures-not-to-be-pushed-to-the-end-of-the-document?rq=1

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Please do not add excessive exclamation marks. It does not help the question, and it will make your question seem unfocussed.

Comment: You could use `\clearpage`to clear the page for the figure. See also [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9191/when-do-i-need-invoke-clearpage-manually].

Comment: As you didn't give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) I can only guess, but you say that you are writing a paper. If it is a scientific paper that uses one of the style files provided by the scientific journals, I could imagine that there is just no "put figure on separate page" provided as this might no comply with the design guidelines of the journal.

Comment: Please provide a MWE on how you include your graphics. Personally I only use relative size to my graphics, that is, `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{...}´ to ensure that the figure fits and to be consequent on graphic size handling throughout all my documents.

Comment: Thanks guys! I figured out. I used \afterpage{\clearpage}

Comment: Related: [Clearpage without pagebreak?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88657/5764)