# Get a "Boxed" page with TeX

Tags: macros

I would like to avoid TikZ or another package. I would like the frame surrounds the page with a rule on all sides and I would like to have a page number  below the frame in the middle. I have some difficulties to understand  how to use `\output` and `shipout`

Comment: You mean rules around the text area of the page, do you?

Comment: yes I would like one or two rules around the text area for every pages

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to avoid using a package?

Comment: No I have to make some texts in plain TeX for friends

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plain TeX solution:

```
\def\frameit#1#2{%
 \vbox{\hrule
  \hbox{%
    \vrule \kern#2pt
      \vbox{\kern#2pt #1
         \kern#2pt}%
      \kern#2pt\vrule}
\hrule}}

\output={%
   \shipout\vbox{%
    \frameit{\box255}9
      \medskip
      \centerline{Test Framed Page}}
  \advancepageno}

\frameit{1}{1}
\bye
```

For any chance to understand output routines start from plain TeX and the TeXBook. See also this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8212/an-explanation-of-latexs-output-routine/8736#8736), where I posted some links to TUGBoat articles about the OTR.

Comment: thanks I was looking for a solution like this. Thanks for the post my problem is how to use `shipout`.

Comment: @Altermundus If you want to hook anything into LaTeX's output routine rather hook at `AtBeginDvi`, have a look at `source2e`.

Comment: [TeX by Topic](http://www.eijkhout.net/tbt/) has a concise explanation of the use of `\output`, section 28.2.

Answer (score 4):

You could draw the rules by yourself inside the header and footer. See e.g. the `layout` package to learn about the exact offsets you have to use.

Here my try which is pretty accurate:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\headsep-\dp\strutbox\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\rlap{\hbox to \textwidth{\hrulefill}}}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\headsep-\textheight-\dp\strutbox\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\vrule height \textheight}%
}
\rhead{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\headsep-\textheight-\dp\strutbox\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\vrule height \textheight}%
}
\lfoot{%
    \raisebox{\footskip}[0pt][0pt]{\rlap{\hbox to \textwidth{\hrulefill}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Interesting and more clear to understand for me but I prefer to avoid the use of a package. This solution can be useful ! thanks now I need to understand the code from Yiannis