# How can I draw a border around a title page?

Tags: color, titles, fancyhdr, framed

I want to draw a red page border only on the title page and signature page of my thesis.
How can I achieve this. I tried the `fancybox` package but it has some conflict with `fancyhdr` package and displayed some of the page headings out of place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a graphic-package like `tikz` or `pstrick` you can use `eso-pic`

```
    \documentclass{scrreprt}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{eso-pic}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \title{Title}
    \author{Name}
    \newcommand{\frameattitle}[1][red]{%
      \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtTextLowerLeft{%
          \color{#1}%
          \linethickness{5pt}%
         \framebox(\LenToUnit{\textwidth},\LenToUnit{\textheight}){}}%
         }%
    }

    \begin{document}
    \frameattitle
    \maketitle
    \clearpage
    \frameattitle
    \null\vfill
    \begin{center}
    \bfseries
    Signature
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \clearpage
    \chapter{foo}
    \lipsum


    \end{document}
```

In relation to the idea of xport here an example with allows a frame around the text size and the paper size.

**EDIT:**

I modified my code. Now you can stretch the frame around the text with the setting of the lengths `extraxsep` and `extraysep`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}
\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\makeatletter
%\frameattext{<backgroundcolor>}{linecolor}{<linewidth>}
\newdimen\extraxsep
\newdimen\extraysep
\extraxsep=20mm
\extraysep=20mm
\newcommand\frameattext[3]{%
  \linethickness{#3}%
  \AddToShipoutPicture*{%
    \AtTextLowerLeft{%%text-boder
       \put(\LenToUnit{-,5\extraxsep},\LenToUnit{-0.5\extraysep}){\color{#1}%
             \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+\extraxsep\relax}{\dimexpr\textheight+\extraysep\relax}}%
       \put(\LenToUnit{-,5\extraxsep},\LenToUnit{-0.5\extraysep}){\color{#2}%
       \framebox(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\textwidth+\extraxsep\relax},%
                 \LenToUnit{\dimexpr\textheight+\extraysep\relax}){}
       }
    }%
  }%
}
%\frameatpage{<backgroundcolor>}{linecolor}{<linewidth>}
\newcommand\frameatpage[3]{%
  \linethickness{#3}%
  \AddToShipoutPicture*{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%%page-border
      \put(0,0){\color{#1}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}%
      \put(\LenToUnit{\@wholewidth},\LenToUnit{\@wholewidth}){%
       \color{#2}\framebox(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2\@wholewidth\relax},%
                  \LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight-2\@wholewidth\relax}){}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\frameattext{green}{blue}{10pt}
\maketitle
\clearpage
\frameatpage{yellow}{red}{6pt}
\null\vfill
\begin{center}
\bfseries
Signature
\end{center}
\vfill
\clearpage
\frameatpage{yellow}{red}{6pt}
\chapter{foo}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

enter image description here

[image]

Comment: Thanks. `\frameattitle` and `\frameattext` works but `\frameatpage` does not. pdflatex complains `"a <box> is suppose to the here"`. Is there a way to increase the space between the text and the box. In my case the box wraps around the text too tightly.

Comment: The example above works fine for me. I use TexLive 2011.

Comment: @Godey: I edited my post. I think during the copy-paste process you forgot to copy the commands `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Comment: I'm aware that this is a ten year old answer - but is there an easy way to make this active on 'this page and all following it'?

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypage*{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}%
  \setlength{\shadowsize}{8pt}%
  \shadowbox}{}
\fancyhead{bar}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}

    Hello world

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I actually required something like this yesterday for my appendix pages of my thesis. Use the `tikz` package and then place the following code somewhere on the title page. This requires two compilation runs to get correct results. Adjust the settings accordantly.

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] {%
    \draw [thick,red!50!black]
    ([shift={(+10mm,-10mm)}]current page.north west)
    rectangle
    ([shift={(-10mm,+10mm)}]current page.south east) 
    ;
}%
```

See also [Use TikZ to draw frontpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/use-tikz-to-draw-frontpage) and [Title page using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9808/title-page-using-tikz) as well as [Get a "Boxed" page with TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15494/get-a-boxed-page-with-tex/15496#15496).

Comment: @Martin: This could be written a bit more elegantly as `\draw [thick,red!50!black] ([shift={(+10mm,-10mm)}]current page.north west) rectangle ([shift={(-10mm,+10mm)}]current page.south east) ;`

Comment: @Jake: Indeed! Funny, I should have known that. I'm just in my last week of thesis write-up and don't have much concentration for anything else :-) I updated my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did:

1. Create a title page by LibreOffice and export it to PDF say, title.pdf
2. Use package wallpaper and include these lines after \begin{document}:

   ```
   \begin{titlepage}
   \ThisLRCornerWallPaper{1}{title.pdf}
   \null
   \vfill
   \end{titlepage}
   ```
3. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,cmyk]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor,calc}

% #1: border color
% #2: background color
% %3: border width
\newcommand\Border[3]{%
    \pagecolor{#1}%
    \newdimen\borderwidth
    \borderwidth=#3
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \color{#2}\hspace{\borderwidth}%
        \rule[\borderwidth]{\paperwidth-2\borderwidth}{\paperheight-2\borderwidth}}}}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\Border{red}{yellow!50}{1cm}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage

\Border{Green}{cyan!30}{1cm}
\lipsum[2]
\newpage

\pagecolor{white}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example works only with `latex-ps-pdf` but not with `pdflatex`

Comment: @Marco: Both `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` and `xelatex` can compile it without problem.

Comment: yeah but I mean the direct compiling to pdf -- `pdflatex foo.tex`.