# What is a BANG float?

Tags: macros, floats, latex-base

This question follows up on [What is the exact purpose of \ftype@<TYPE>?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32359/what-is-the-exact-purpose-of-ftypetype/32384#32384). The LaTeX kernel source refers to a `BANG float` in the `ltoutput.dtx`, but there is no explanation for it. Anybody knows what it is?

Comment: Fun Fact: If you google "bang float latex", the first hit is about balloons, the second the TeX UK-FAQ about floats (not mentioning BANG) and the third is already this question (9min old right now).

Comment: Yiannis, @lockstep: I think the [tex-core] tag doesn't belong here. Would be a candidate again for the to-be-discussed [latex-core] tag.

Comment: bang float are floats with an "!" float option. I guess the name came from  the same source as "shebang" and "hash-bang" for "#!". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I believe using 'bang' for '!' is originally a printers term

Comment: @lockstep suggest `latex-kernel` tag for this sort of thing, will be easier to Google and more kid-proof:)

Comment: @JosephWright According to Webster's you got the prize, although based on Ulrike's comment the influence might have come from "shebang", wish is the latter; this word originates from Irish and is used in South Africa as "[shebeen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebeen)". As we all hate unanswered questions, will you please put your comment as an answer?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I think Ulrike's comment is the correct answer from a TeX point-of-view.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Will you please write your comment and a few words as an answer, so that I can accept it? I think Joseph's comment is also possibly a reasonable explanation but he is an officer and a gentleman!:)

Comment: In algebraic topology, it's often pronounced "shriek" since that's what you do when you see it (it often denotes a map going in the opposite way to what you expect).

Comment: @AndrewStacey: I don't think that's why most people shriek when they see one of those.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

bang float are floats with an "!" float option. I guess the name came from the same source as the bang in "shebang" and "hash-bang" for "#!". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix).

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclamation_mark:

> In the 1950's, secretarial dictation and typesetting manuals referred
>   to the mark as "bang," most likely adapted from comic books
>   where the ! appeared in dialogue balloons to represent a gun being
>   fired, although the nickname probably emerged from letterpress
>   printing. This bang usage is behind the titles of the
>   interrobang, an uncommon typographic character, and a shebang line, a
>   feature of unix computer systems.