# Unable to include figure

Tags: graphics

I was trying to include figures in my LaTeX file like this :

```
\begin{figure} 
\centering
 \includegraphics[scale =0.5]{graph/jm90-10/1.jpg}
   \caption{ Job Mix 90:10 (CPU:Disk) Topology Mix 10:90 (CPU:Disk)  }
 \end{figure}

\begin{figure}   
\centering
 \includegraphics[scale =0.5]{graph/jm90-10/2.jpg}
    \caption{ Job Mix 90:10 (CPU:Disk) Topology Mix 30:70 (CPU:Disk)  }
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}   
\centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{graph/jm90-10/3.jpg}
    \caption{ Job Mix 90:10 (CPU:Disk) Topology Mix 50:50 (CPU:Disk)  }
 \end{figure}
```

The figure 1.jpg gets inserted but not other two.
The error comes at line 3 of second figure at `\includegraphics`... as follows

```
l.253 \centering
You've lost some text. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! Undefined control sequence.
\@xfloat ...@fltovf \fi \global \setbox \@currbox
\color@vbox \normalcolor \...
l.253 \centering
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\vbox
l.253 \centering
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
<graph/jm90-10/3.jpg, id=83, 783.92876pt x 458.71375pt>
File: graph/jm90-10/3.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
<use graph/jm90-10/3.jpg>
Overfull \hbox (1.96342pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 254--255
[][]
[]
! Undefined control sequence.
\@largefloatcheck ->\ifdim \ht \@currbox
>\textheight \@tempdima -\textheigh...
l.256 \end{figure}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
>
```

Any help ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. The code snippets you have look okay, so the issue is likely to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 13):

It looks very similar to a problem written on LaTeX-Community.org: [Can't include the 19th figure](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=7109). There we see the same error message

```
You've lost some text. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit
?
! Undefined control sequence.
\@xfloat ...@fltovf \fi \global \setbox \@currbox
\color@vbox \normalcolor \...
```

but before this came

```
! LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats.
```

Perhaps you did not see that. Very probably you have too many floats stored.

Possible solutions:

- Improve the figure (floats) placement by setting placement options, such as

  ```
  \begin{figure}[!htbp]
  ```

  See: [How to use the placement options [t], [h] with figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35125/how-to-use-the-placement-options-t-h-with-figures)
- Take care that your figures would not be too big to fit in the text area
- Issue a `\clearpage` to force the output of stored floats at some time
- Use the [`morefloats`](http://ctan.org/pkg/morefloats) package

Comment: @arun: If Stefan's answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it by clicking the check mark below the vote count of this answer.