# You've lost some text

Tags: floats, errors

I had several figures included in my `.tex`  file with the use of `\usepackage{graphicx}` written like the following:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\center
\includegraphics{compton.jpg}
\caption{Compton scattering}
\end{figure}
```

They were all compiling fine yet after writing some basic text elsewhere on the page, when I tried to compile it said:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
You've lost some text. Try typing return to proceed
```

Can anyone shed light as to what may have occured?

Comment: no sorry that's a typo here

Comment: I think you have too many figures. See: [Unable to include figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46059/unable-to-include-figure). And [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 6):

`You've lost some text. Try typing return to proceed` is the help text that you get if you respond to an error with `h`. most likely the error was `Float(s) lost` although that help text is used in other places so it is hard to be sure given the information you posted.

Using `[ht]` restricts the places where LaTeX can place floats so makes this error more likely, try to *always* include `p` in the optional argument (if you use it at all), then normally if too many floats build up, LaTeX can make float pages to flush them out. Otherwise as a last resort you can use `\clearpage` to force the floats to appear.

Comment: Sorry I am new to latex and didn't tell you the correct error. It says 'Error: Not in outer par mode.' A quick look online suggests that this is usually due to attempting to put figures in tables and things like that. The problem here is they were working and I didn't change them.

Comment: @Evan: You should never put the figure-environment inside another environment. It doesn't make sense: figure wants to float. But you can use without problem the `\includegraphics` inside tabulars etc.

Comment: If they were working and now they are not, someone has changed something:-) As @UlrikeFischer says you have a figure inside a table or a box or something. The solution is not to do that, but without seeing an example it is hard to say exactly what to change.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the help. I found the issue. I hadn't closed off my abstract with \end{abstract}