# How do I fix "Error: Float(s) lost"?

Tags: floats

Recently I changed the entire style of some class notes to tufte and I have a lot of error, also I made the change gradually but in this last part things that worked out stoped working out. One of those thins are the chapters that gives me the next error that I don't understand:

[image]

Please help and thanks for reading

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example and not just a screenshot. The error message points you to the manual or to the book "the latex companion". ButI hope you do not need to buy a book to resolve... If you provide a complete example with code, somebody here will hopefully help you for free. 

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48988/15036

Comment: @mickep Ther are more than 4000 lines of code and I don't know where and why the error strated because a week ago I didn´t have it