# Floatplacement with short paragraph

Tags: floats

I do not know why the picture ends up on a page of its own, IMHO it should fit perfectly fine on the page with the paragraph, however I get a two page document.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}  
%place floats in subsections
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\subsection\expandafter
    {\expandafter\@fb@secFB\subsection}%
}
\makeatother    
\begin{document}
\subsection{Tile}
\begin{figure}
    \adjustbox{max width={\linewidth}}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=.5\linewidth]{file}}
    \caption{Tile}\label{fig:tile}
\end{figure}
A black tile on the wall is shown in \ref{fig:tile}. While this text is short we need a new page for the picture. The author does not know why, but maybe somebody on \emph{tex.stackexchange.com} does?
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The figure does not fit in that page within the constraints set. `placeins` won't let it float to the top so going before the section head, you have not allowed `h` so the only possibility is `b` or `p` but the float is too big for `b` as the default in report is

```
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.3}
```

If you allow bigger bottom floats by putting

```
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.5}
```

in the preamble it will go there.

As it is `p` is the only possibility so it ends on a float page.

Answer (score 0):

additional thoughts after getting the answer from David Carlisle:

The [`float`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/float) package can be used to set the default placement options for a float, e.g. `\floatplacement{figure}{tp}`.

Adding `before` or `after` to the package options for [`placeins`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/placeins) allows the float to appear above or below the section if it si on the same page.

[this awnser](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35130/19326) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/19326) contain useful information on more float constraints that can be modified.