# How to insert a page break between a figure and its caption?

Tags: floats, captions

Is it possible to insert a page break or put the figure caption on the following page. The figure is too big for both the figure and caption to fit on a single page.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figure.pdf}
\caption{caption} 
\label{label}
\end{figure}
```

Using `\clearpage` or `\pagebreak` before `\caption` doesn't work.

Cheers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you're already loading the `caption` package, you could proceed as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[p] % this "float" will reside on a floats-only page
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figure.pdf}
% note: no \caption and \label for now
\end{figure}
\clearpage % insert a page break
\captionof{figure}{caption} 
\label{label}
```

To create some unambiguous visual separation between the caption and the remaining material on that page, you could insert instructions such as `\hrule\bigskip` following `\label`.

---

That said, are you sure it's necessary to display the image file so large that the caption won't fit on the same page? E.g., you could try writing

```
\includegraphics[height=0.9\textheight]{Figure.pdf}
```

This should provide enough remaining space on the page to permit the caption being typeset on that page as well.

Comment: what do I put in the figure part of the  \caption{figure}{caption}

Comment: @Jaco495 - you'd put the actual text of the caption where it now says "caption".

Comment: I tried to use this, but another figure ended up appearing before my caption, which is annoying. I wanted to have a way to put the caption as the first thing on the following page. This is the kind of thing that makes LaTeX annoying... :-(

Comment: @HomeroEsmeraldo - Your description of the issue you're facing (and of why the method shown above, which I wrote more than five years ago by now, doesn't "work" for you) is quite terse. if I understood you correctly, an issue not addressed by answer may arise if several floats are in the queue and get flushed all at once. Please consider posting a new query in which you lay out in detail what you're trying to achieve, what you've done so far, and which issues you (still) need to resolve. Thanks.

Comment: @Mico, sorry for the bad mood and thanks for your solution using the caption package, it was the best I found. I have now have managed to fix my issue by forcing the placement of the other figure (the one that appeared before the caption) to go to a different page by using [h] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35125/how-to-use-the-placement-options-t-h-with-figures). Is there any reason that \label should be placed with the caption and not with the figure? I left it in the figure environment

Comment: @HomeroEsmeraldo - Glad you were able to work out the (remaining) issues. For floats, the `\label` must always come *after* the caption if you want cross-references (via `\ref`) to the floats to be correct. Put differently, the `figure` environment does *not* increment the `figure` counter; the counter incrementing is performed by `\caption` (or `\captionof`).