# Sideways figures captions on previous page

Tags: captions, rotating

My thesis guidelines specify that a full page figure must have it's caption on a preceding page, also on it's own page. For rotated figures I would like to be able to rotate these captions as well.

Combining the advice offered in:

[Full-page figure with preceding caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205234/full-page-figure-with-preceding-caption?rq=1)

[How to insert a page break between a figure and its caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182689/how-to-insert-a-page-break-between-a-figure-and-its-caption)

I settled on the following code to generate the caption on the preceding page, with the unfortunate loss of rotated captioning offered by the sidewaysfigure environment, which i would like to preserve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\newpage
\captionof{figure}[figure short caption]{Long figure caption ... \lipsum[4]}
\newpage
\label{figurelabel}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[p!]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{figure.pdf}
\label{figurelabel}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\clearpage
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Is there a fix for this? I tried using the \turnbox command on the \captionof command (e.g. 
`\captionof{figure}[figure short caption]{\turnbox{270}{Long figure caption ... \lipsum[4]}}`), and I'm aware that there is a \rotcaption command in the caption package, but cannot seem to settle on a workable combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\newpage
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[p!]
\caption[figure short caption]{Long figure caption ... \lipsum[4]}
\label{figurelabel}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[p!]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{figure.pdf}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\clearpage
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I put the caption in `sidewaysfigure` environment and left label only there. Is it ok?

Comment: Fantastic, Zarko. For some reason this never occurred to me; I suppose I thought it would alter the figure count, but it does not.

Comment: Glad to help you. Figure count is tied to caption, not with figure environment.