# Adding a picture correctly

Tags: diagrams, text

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm writing a report with it. In the beginning everything is okay but when I insert a picture the text is disturbed and moved from its place and the text that is supposed to be after the picture is written before it. Please help me

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Without a minimal working example, it'll be hard to help…

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example  [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` (including only relevant packages) that still illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code.

Comment: This answer may be helpful. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/24974

Comment: If you are using the `figure` environment to place the picture, it is a "float" that will float to the place LaTeX thinks best.  You can override the default float behavior by invoking it with `\begin{figure}[hb] ... \end{figure}`.  The `h` says try to place the figure "here" where I made the call, and if not possible, the `b` says to place the figure at the bottom of the page.

Comment: If my answer solved the problem then please accept it :).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps for a start. Please make sure that you read [How to use the placement options [t], [h] with figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35125) for example regarding the different **placement options** for so-called **floating objects** like figures and tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Provides the [H] placement option
\usepackage{float}

% Just for some random text
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[H] % H --> Here and nowhere else :)
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Caption of the nice example picture.}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]