# All the picture move to the end of the chapter

Tags: floats, diagrams

Halo, I used latex for writing my thesis. In chapter 3 a lot of pictures inside. Unfortunately, all the pictures move to the end of the chapter, like the picture attached below. I used this code to insert the picture.

```
\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{baganRL.jpg}
\caption{Interaksi antara agen dan lingkungan pada \textit{Finite Markov Decision Processes}}\label{baganMDP}
\end{figure}
```

Anyone can help; what's wrong? Because in other chapters, the picture is in the right place.

[image]

Comment: You don't give us much to go on but if a picture can't fit on a page then it is moved to the end and other pictures will follow.

Comment: Try with `[htbp!]`   and *study*  the answers to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35130/11604) questions