# When specifying placement of floats, is the list prioritized?

Tags: floats, positioning

When specifying a float's placement, e.g. `[htpb]`, is the order of the arguments specifying the priority of them?

Example:

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{sampleImage}
\caption{Example caption}
\label{fig:sampleImage} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: General note: `\label` always belongs *after* `\caption`, otherwise you label the last label-able item instead.

Comment: AFAIK, the order of the placement characters is not meaningful. But I don't know enough about it to post a full answer.

Comment: AFAIK the order is irrelevant. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32359/what-is-the-exact-purpose-of-ftypetype

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: I was not very awake this morning. I just noticed there is an undelete option, so I did that.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Thank you for that correction, I was not aware of that at all.

Comment: Note: Placing the label inside of (instead of after) the caption works, too: `\caption{Example caption\label{fig:sampleImage}}`.

Comment: There a long explanation of how the float algorithm works andh ow it can be influenced: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, the order of the placement options is irrelevant. Every placement option will be stored as bit in a single value, so `[tb]` and `[bt]` will give the same value and therefore will have the same result.

See [What is the exact purpose of \ftype@<TYPE>?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32359/what-is-the-exact-purpose-of-ftypetype) for implementation details.

Answer (score 9):

- if `!` is given, ignore all settings by the parameters, like vertical
  space, number of floats, etc
- if `h` is given, try to place it `here`, if not possible then change
  `h` to `t`, the float then can appear on top of the *next* page
- if `t` is given try to place it on top of the current *or*  next
  page.
- if `b` is given try to place it on bottom of the current *or*  next
  page.
- if `p` is given place the float on the next page without additional
  text.

Comment: The question is about if the order matters, not what the single character do. If your list is a priority order, please state so explicitly.

Comment: Not actually addressing the question but did improve my understanding of how LaTeX treats these parameters. It's a better explanation than the table on http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures

Answer (score 4):

The order of placement is irrelevant.
You can try it to see for yourself.

```
\documentclass{octavo}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[tb]
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\end{figure}

Another line ...
\end{document}
```

Changing `tb` or `bt`  still results in the same output. The 'here' also is immaterial where you place it. Change [bh] and will be placed correctly as 'here'.

Comment: Some official reference with explanation would be much better than "you can try it yourself".

Comment: @MartinScharrer Martin sure, but as AFAIK there is nothing other than the official source2e algorithm and is painfully long   and obscure. Will try and summarize when I get some time. Anyway I thought that proving a hypothesis by experiment was an approved scientific method since the Renaissance and the example clearly demonstrates the answer to the OP's question.:)

Comment: There is official documentation (in book form) such as the book by Leslie Lamport and TLC. That is the reference documentation. And I would think that the lshort documentation would also cover it (not checked though). And here on the site there is: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Could you please also have a look a http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32359/what-is-the-exact-purpose-of-ftypetype