# Caption placement for new float in tufte-book class

Tags: floats, captions, tufte

I am using the `tufte-book` document class and I am trying to create a new float environment for example boxes that will include captions in the right margin similar to table/figure captions.

However, when I create the new float environment, the caption appears above the float on the left.

MWE included below:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{framed, color}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name=Example]{example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
\caption{Currently, this caption is left justified above the float, when I would like it to be in the right margin similar to the table caption below.}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.3}
\begin{shaded}
\lipsum[2]
\end{shaded}
\end{example}

\begin{table}
\caption{This is how I want the new float environment caption to behave.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llr}
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
Value A1 & Value A2 & Value A3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our new user page [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get more info on how to get the most out of this site.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/12/

Comment: ...resolved with `newfloat` v1.1-91 (will be uploaded to CTAN today)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using the `newfloat` package, you can create the example floating object in a fashion similar to the one used for the `tufte` classes; this will give you the possibility to automatically inherit the desired formatting. In the following example I defined the `example` floating object from scratch, using the "`tufte` way"; the code follows the `tufte` definitions for `figure` and `table`, which can be found in the file `tufte-common.def`: I also made the necessary provisions for a possible `\listofexamples`:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{framed, color}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{example}[chapter]
\newcommand\examplename{Example}
\newcommand\listexamplename{List of Examples}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofexamples{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@tufte@class}{book}}%
    {\chapter*{\listexamplename}}%
    {\section*{\listexamplename}}%
%  \begin{fullwidth}%
    \@starttoc{loe}%
%  \end{fullwidth}%
}
\renewcommand\theexample
     {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@example}
\def\fps@example{tbp}
\def\ftype@example{1}
\def\ext@example{loe}
\def\fnum@example{\examplename\nobreakspace\theexample}
\newenvironment{example}[1][htbp]
  {\begin{@tufte@float}[#1]{example}{}}
  {\end{@tufte@float}}
\let\l@example\l@figure
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
\caption{Currently, this caption is in the right margin similar to the table caption below.}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.3}
\begin{shaded}
\lipsum[2]
\end{shaded}
\end{example}

\begin{table}
\caption{This is how I want the new float environment caption to behave.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llr}
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
Value A1 & Value A2 & Value A3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want all your `example` environments to be with a colored background, you can include the coloring environment directly in the definition of `example`. The following example illustrates this, but using the `mdframed` environment (from the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package) instead of `shaded` (from the `framed` package); this gives a better vertical alignment between the object and the caption (compare with the example above):

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.3}

\newcounter{example}[chapter]
\newcommand\examplename{Example}
\newcommand\listexamplename{List of Examples}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofexamples{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@tufte@class}{book}}%
    {\chapter*{\listexamplename}}%
    {\section*{\listexamplename}}%
%  \begin{fullwidth}%
    \@starttoc{loe}%
%  \end{fullwidth}%
}
\renewcommand\theexample
     {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@example}
\def\fps@example{tbp}
\def\ftype@example{1}
\def\ext@example{loe}
\def\fnum@example{\examplename\nobreakspace\theexample}
\newenvironment{example}[1][htbp]
  {\begin{@tufte@float}[#1]{example}{}
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=shadecolor,hidealllines=true]}
  {\end{mdframed}\end{@tufte@float}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
\caption{Currently, this caption is in the right margin similar to the table caption below.}
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\begin{table}
\caption{This is how I want the new float environment caption to behave.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llr}
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
Value A1 & Value A2 & Value A3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Reference for the requirement of `\ftype@.`, `\fps@.`, `\ext@.` and `\fnum@.` is available from [Frank's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46259/5764) to [What is the exact purpose of `\ftype@<TYPE>`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32359/5764)

Comment: Great and complete answer! The OP may wish to adjust the vertical spacing of the `example` environment by about `-0.5\baselineskip` due to `framed`'s downward vertical adjustment.