# Meaning of floattype in KOMA

Tags: floats, koma-script

Friends, I've been happily using KOMA for some time now, and yesterday I was intrigued by a particular option when using `\DeclareNewTOC`:

> `floattype = <number>`: The numerical float type of the defined floats. Float types with common bits cannot be reordered. At the standard classes figures has float type 1 and tables has float type 2. If no float type was given, 16 will be used.

Is there any convention for float types? Is it just an internal representation? What are the effects of this option in a document?

I'm lost. `:)` Can someone enlighten my path? `:)`

Comment: Did you see [What is the exact purpose of `\ftype@<TYPE>`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32359/)

Comment: @egreg: oh my, I was unaware of that! I think I'll delete my question, your answer in that thread explains the float types perfectly.

Comment: Inside `scrartcl.cls` `\newcommand*{\ftype@table}{2}` and `\newcommand*{\ftype@figure}{1}` are shown and little more details in [german version,`floattype=Gleittyp` page 301](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide.pdf). Chap 13 english is "This chapter has been generated from the source of the package. It’s not a 1-to-1 translation of the German
manual. Currently translation has not been finished".