# Why is my paper shorter in LaTeX than in Libreoffice?

Tags: spacing

I typeset the same paper in Libreoffice and in LaTex. Both were in the same font and used the same (MLA) format.

Why is the LaTeX version produce a PDF that is a few lines shorter?

Comment: (Well) justified text often results in less whitespace than non-justified or not well justified text.  If the LL document is five pages and the LaTeX one only one page, I'd be amazed.  If it's a difference of a few lines, direct your admiration to TeX' superior typesetting abilities.

Comment: Both of these are only left justified. BTW this is ~5 lines out of 8-9 pages

Comment: This cannot be answered definitely, only guesses are possible. I would suspect the output routine of TeX is better. BTW: Same font in Open-/Truetype or Type1? Same margin settings? _Edit:_ [An explanation of LaTeX's output routine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8212).