# LaTeX sphack family of commands

Tags: spacing, programming

LaTeX offers a number of commands that can be used in macros that want to be invisible i.e., not leave any extra space when used in the middle of text. These macros include `\@esphack`, `\@bsphack`, `\@Esphack`, `\@vbsphack` and can be found in `ltspace.dtx`.

Amongst all these commands  `\@vbsphack` stands alone as it is described in the source, but not implemented and commented as follows:

> Another variant which is useful for
>   invisible things which should not live
>   in `vmode` (this is how some people feel
>   about marginals). If it occurs in
>   vmode then it enters hmode and ensures
>   that `\@savsk` is nonzero so that the
>   `\ignorespaces` is put in later. It is
>   not used at present.

The macro definition is copied below:

```
\def \@vbsphack{ %
\relax \ifvmode
\leavevmode
\@savsk 1sp
\@savsf \spacefactor
\else
\ifhmode
\@savsk \lastskip
\@savsf \spacefactor
\fi
\fi
}
```

Can someone explain why should the `\@savsk` should be non-zero? The explanation offered in the source is not very clear.

Lastly as I am sure the name of these macros is [not a lisp relic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/lisp-relics-in-latexe-logo), can anyone offer the origin or history of how the family name was derived?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can help at least on the naming: these are 'space hacks' to try to avoid messing up spacing with commands that 'do nothing' in output terms. So you have `\@bsphack` = 'begin space hack', `\@esphack` = 'end space hack'. I think `\@Esphack` is intended only for floats, but on this I'm not certain.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it! I was going to ask a colleague about it but I was afraid he was going to swear back at me:)

Answer (score 8):

Joseph answered the naming question (I have always liked the idea of an esp hack).

The reason for making `\@savsk` nonzero is because it moves into horizontal mode (`\leavevmode`) and `\@esphack` checks if `\@savsk` is positive. If it is, then it uses `\ignorespaces` to gobble space tokens (as the quote says).

I'm not terribly sure I follow what this could be used for though.