# What are the uses of \@bsphack & \@esphack

Tags: macros

I see the macro duo:

```
 \@bsphack ... code ... \@esphack
```

appearing in different places. I noted that it suppresses spaces around
the macro in which these commands are used, but when do you need to use
them in your own macros / are there other use cases?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8271/latex-sphack-family-of-commands/8272#8272 also

Comment: Relevant/related: [How to make a command completely empty / invisible / non-existent?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201817/5764), [How to define commands that do not consume any space](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130012/5764), [Patching commands to remove surrounding whitespace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68737/5764)